# Learning Go: How To INSERT a post request to Database?

Tags: function, go, post, endpoint

### Adding Information to DB

I want to update my DB, and add a row (in my case its a new "container")
this is the function:

```golang
func (c ContainerController) AddContainer(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var errorMessage entities.Error
        container := new(entities.Container)
        //Takes host_id and image_name from POST request and save into container variable
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&container)
        //If something wrong in POST request or
        //If at least one field missed information -> print Error and return from this function
        if container.HostId == 0 || container.ImageName == "" || err != nil {
            errorMessage.Message = "Error: Missing fields or wrong input"
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
            return
        }
        uuidWithHyphen := uuid.New()
        uuid := uuidWithHyphen.String()
        container.Name = uuid
        _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO containers(id, host_id ,name, image_name) VALUES(c.id, c.host_id, c.name, c.image_name)")
        if err != nil {
            errorMessage.Message = "Error: Insert into container"
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, errorMessage)
            return
        }
        //Convert containers content to JSON representation
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        utils.SendSuccess(w, container)
    }
}
```

every time I make a post request I get this error "Error: Insert into container"...
This is the main.go with endpoint

```golang
func main() {
    db := config.GetDB() //Establishing connection to DBase
    {

        router := mux.NewRouter()
        router.HandleFunc("/", HomePage)
        router.HandleFunc("/hello", Welcome)
        router.HandleFunc("/about", AboutPage)

        c := controllers.ContainerController{}
        router.Handle("/create-container", c.AddContainer(db))
    }

}
```

This is the josn that I used to test it:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "host_id": 2,
    "image_name": "AMP - Cubecoders"
}
```

not sure what I did incorctly

Comment: `VALUES (c.id, c.host_id, c.name, c.image_name)` -- The character `c` in a string is just that, a character. Nothing more. It's not a variable referencing the receiver of the method. In Go there's no "automatic" string interpolation where you can inject values from the string's surrounding scope.

Comment: To send data to the database you need to use parameter placeholders in the SQL query and then pass the data to the [`Exec`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.19#DB.Exec) method alongside the SQL string. And the placeholder syntax will vary based on the db backend and the driver used to communicate with the backend. For example

Comment: Expand the example in the `ExecContext` documentation found [here](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.19#DB.ExecContext) to see how data is sent to the database. Notice the `?` placeholder (MySQL specific) in the SQL query and the `id` variable passed alongside the SQL string.

Comment: @mkopriva 
```go
db.Exec("INSERT INTO containers(id, host_id ,name, image_name) VALUES (id, host_id, name, image_name)", container.ID, container.HostId, container.Name, container.ImageName)
```
this is the correct way, or I am not missing something?

Comment: `(id, host_id, name, image_name)` are not valid placeholders. At least not in those databases with which I am familiar.

Comment: And try not to squeeze code into comments. Instead you should update your question with the new code and also include the exact and complete error message you received when trying to execute the new code.

Comment: @mkopriva you are right , I was doing it wrong... had to use the `?`... 
thanks